# Spring 3.0: Annotation of a scheduled task using *.conf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I use Spring 3.0 to annotate a scheduled task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${UPDATE_RATE}")
```

However, I want to store the properties in `application.conf`, not `application.properties`:

```
conf {
    UPDATE_RATE = 60000
}
```

It looks like Spring cannot find `UPDATE_RATE` in the file `application.conf`, because it expects `application.properties`.

Is there any way to use `*.conf` instead of `*.properties`?

Comment: Did you tried using the @PropertySource annotation? Exemaple: @PropertySource("file:/{selected location}/application.conf"

Comment: @MauroM: Where should I use it? If I put this annotation before `@Scheduled...`, then it says `@PropertySource not applicable to method`